# Extract Date from list of Dates and switch on/off parameters based on criteria VBA Access

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, ms-access, if-statement

I'd like to come up with a function that checks a particular Date, against the below array of dates and returns the previous Year-End Date and the previous Month-End Date. In addition, i'd also like to perform two additional checks on a second date and return True/False based on (1) is Y_Date the exact Month-End date and (2) is Y_Date the exact Year-End date.

Here's the basic code I've come up with so far, however i'm wondering if there's a neater way of doing this.

```
DateArray = Array("29/12/2017", "29/06/2018", "31/07/2018", "31/08/2018", "28/09/2018", "31/10/2018", "30/11/2018", "31/12/2018", "31/01/2019", "28/02/2019", "29/03/2019", "30/04/2019", "31/05/2019", "28/06/2019", "31/07/2019", "30/08/2019", "30/09/2019", "31/10/2019", "29/11/2019", "31/12/2019")

L_Date = CDate("11/07/2018")
Y_Date = CDate("10/07/2018")

For Each e In DateArray
    If Month(CDate(e)) = (Month(L_Date) - 1) And Year(CDate(e)) = (Year(L_Date)) Then
        ME_Date = CDate(e)
    ElseIf Month(CDate(e)) = 12 And Month(L_Date) = 1 And Year(CDate(e)) = (Year(L_Date) - 1) Then
        ME_Date = CDate(e)
    Exit For
    End If
Next e

For Each e In DateArray
    If Month(CDate(e)) = 12 And Year(CDate(e)) = (Year(L_Date) - 1) Then
        YE_Date = CDate(e)
    Exit For
    End If
Next e

For Each e In DateArray
    MECheck = False
    YECheck = False
    If StrComp(CDate(e), CDate(Y_Date)) = 0 Then
        MECheck = True
        If Month(CDate(Y_Date)) = 12 Then
            YECheck = True
        End If
        Exit For
    End If
Next e
```

Essentially the process (by example of a case) should work like this:

**Case:**

L_Date = **15/11/2018** and 
Y_Date = **14/11/2018** returns the following:

- ME_Date = 31/10/2018 (previous month end date)
- YE_Date = 29/12/2017 (previous year end date)
- MECheck = False (since Y_Date is not the 30/11/2018)
- YECheck = False (since Y_Date is not the 31/12/2018)

Thank you for your help and any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why `YE_Date = 29/12/2017`?? Any End of year is 31/12/****. Why 29?

Comment: Apologies, forgot to comment on that! Basically the list consists of last working day/weekday of the month. This is why I have the checks carried out against a manually populated array of dates (i don't have to worry about creating a function that avoids holidays/weekends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Access (which, by your question tags you are), I would **strongly** reccomend that you store your custom dates in a table, rather than hard-coded in an array. That way, updating your dates is easier and you have the added benefit of running reports off of them.

And, regarding your comment

> This is why I have the checks carried out against a manually populated array of dates (i don't have to worry about creating a function that avoids holidays/weekends)

I would argue that it's actually easier in the long run to write functions to skip weekends and holidays. I would start with creating a table to store your holidays. Then write a function similar to the following to check if a given date is a holiday:

```
' this function uses the Holidays table ('tHolidays')
' to see if a provided date is a holiday
' uses DLookup rather than parameterized query for speed
Function IsHoliday(ByVal MyDate As Date) As Boolean
   Dim sFilter As String
   Dim record As Variant

   sFilter = "HolidayDate = #" & MyDate & "#"
   record = DLookup("HolidayDate", "tHolidays", sFilter)
   IsHoliday = Not IsNull(record)
End Function
```

Your function to check if a given date is a weekend is also quite simple:

```
Function IsWeekendDay(ByVal MyDate as Date, _
        optional weekendDay1 as VbDayOfWeek = vbSaturday, _
        optional weekendDay2 as VbDayOfWeek = vbSunday) _
as boolean

    Dim weekday as Integer

    weekday = datepart("w", MyDate)
    IsWeekendDay = (weekday = weekendDay1) Or (weekday = weekendDay2)

End Function
```

You could reword your code to add new functions to determine a given month's end, or a given year end. Something like this:

```
Function GetYearEnd(pYear as Integer) as Date
    GetYearEnd = DateSerial(Year:=pYear, Month:=12, Day:=31)

    Do Until Not (IsHoliday(GetYearEnd) or IsWeekendDay(GetYearEnd))
        GetYearEnd = GetYearEnd - 1
    Loop
End Function

Function GetMonthEnd(pYear as Integer, pMonth as Integer)
    ' start with the 1st of the month
    GetMonthEnd = DateSerial(Year:=pYear, Month:=pMonth, Day:=1)

    ' the last calendar day of the month is 
    ' 1 less than the first day of the next month
    ' this approach means we won't have to worry about leap years
    GetMonthEnd = DateAdd("m", 1, GetMonthEnd) - 1

    Do Until Not (IsHoliday(GetMonthEnd) Or IsWeekendDay(GetMonthEnd))
        GetMonthEnd = GetMonthEnd - 1
    Loop
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I must admit I designed a totally different code from yours, because working with dates it's easier on Excel, so I added a reference to Excel in Access.

[image]

After that, I used natural WorksheetFunctions in Excel to design 4 Functions to get the natural dates in each case (previous end of year, previous end of month, end of current month and end of current year).

```
Private Function PREV_YEAR_ED(ByVal ThisDate As Date) As Date
PREV_YEAR_ED = CDate("31/12/" & Year(WorksheetFunction.EDate(CDate(ThisDate), -12)))
End Function

Private Function PREV_MONTH_ED(ByVal ThisDate As Date) As Date
PREV_MONTH_ED = CDate(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(CDate(ThisDate), -1))
End Function

Private Function MONTH_ED(ByVal ThisDate As Date) As Date
MONTH_ED = CDate(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(CDate(ThisDate), 0))
End Function

Private Function YEAR_ED(ByVal ThisDate As Date) As Date
YEAR_ED = CDate("31/12/" & Year(ThisDate))
End Function
```

After that, I designed the macro with the data you have posted. The boolean checks are easy to get `False` or `True` just with a simple If.

But getting the previous Year-End Date and the previous Month-End Date you need to loop all the dates. From the dates in the array, you need to get the closest date to your data, and also must be equal or smaller than your data.

So the code checks the difference between dates, stores the array index with the minimun differente between dates, and returns that value.

```
Sub MACRO()

Dim DateArray As Variant

Dim L_Date, Y_Date, ME_Date, YE_Date, TargetDate As Date
Dim MECheck, YECheck As Boolean

Dim i As Integer

L_Date = CDate("15/11/2018")
Y_Date = CDate("14/11/2018")

DateArray = Array("29/12/2017", "29/06/2018", "31/07/2018", "31/08/2018", "28/09/2018", "31/10/2018", "30/11/2018", "31/12/2018", "31/01/2019", "28/02/2019", "29/03/2019", "30/04/2019", "31/05/2019", "28/06/2019", "31/07/2019", "30/08/2019", "30/09/2019", "31/10/2019", "29/11/2019", "31/12/2019")

'AVAILABLE FUNCTIONS
'PREV_YEAR_ED will get the natural last day of the previous year, according to the value of ThisDate
'PREV_MONTH_ED will get the natural last day of the previous month, according to the value of ThisDate
'MONTH_ED will get the natural last day of current month, according to the value of ThisDate
'YEAR_ED will get the natural last day of current year, according to the value of ThisDate

'Case L_Date = 15/11/2018 and Y_Date = 14/11/2018 returns the following:
'ME_Date = 31/10/2018 (previous month end date)
'YE_Date = 29/12/2017 (previous year end date)
'MECheck = False (since Y_Date is not the 30/11/2018)
'YECheck = False (since Y_Date is not the 31/12/2018)


Dim DifDays, MinDifDays As Integer
Dim idx As Integer


'to get ME_Date
TargetDate = PREV_MONTH_ED(L_Date)

'ME_DATE will be a date on the array with minimun difference between natural previous month end date (TargetDate)
' and smaller or equal than TargetDate. We need to find with index of the array has the value we want

MinDifDays = 999
For i = 0 To UBound(DateArray) Step 1
    If TargetDate = CDate(DateArray(i)) Then
        idx = i
        Exit For
    ElseIf TargetDate > CDate(DateArray(i)) Then
        DifDays = L_Date - CDate(DateArray(i))
        If DifDays < MinDifDays Then
            MinDifDays = DifDays
            idx = i
        End If
    End If
Next i

ME_Date = CDate(DateArray(idx))

'to get YE_Date
TargetDate = PREV_YEAR_ED(L_Date)

'YE_Date will be a date on the array with minimun difference between natural previous year end date (TargetDate)
' and smaller or equal than TargetDate. We need to find with index of the array has the value we want

MinDifDays = 999
For i = 0 To UBound(DateArray) Step 1
    If TargetDate = CDate(DateArray(i)) Then
        idx = i
        Exit For
    ElseIf TargetDate > CDate(DateArray(i)) Then
        DifDays = L_Date - CDate(DateArray(i))
        If DifDays < MinDifDays Then
            MinDifDays = DifDays
            idx = i
        End If
    End If
Next i

YE_Date = CDate(DateArray(idx))

'boolean checks

If Y_Date = MONTH_ED(Y_Date) Then
    MECheck = True
Else
    MECheck = False
End If

If Y_Date = YEAR_ED(Y_Date) Then
    YECheck = True
Else
    YECheck = False
End If


Debug.Print ME_Date
Debug.Print YE_Date
Debug.Print MECheck
Debug.Print YECheck

Erase DateArray

End Sub
Private Function PREV_YEAR_ED(ByVal ThisDate As Date) As Date
PREV_YEAR_ED = CDate("31/12/" & Year(WorksheetFunction.EDate(CDate(ThisDate), -12)))
End Function

Private Function PREV_MONTH_ED(ByVal ThisDate As Date) As Date
PREV_MONTH_ED = CDate(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(CDate(ThisDate), -1))
End Function

Private Function MONTH_ED(ByVal ThisDate As Date) As Date
MONTH_ED = CDate(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(CDate(ThisDate), 0))
End Function

Private Function YEAR_ED(ByVal ThisDate As Date) As Date
YEAR_ED = CDate("31/12/" & Year(ThisDate))
End Function
```

If I execute this code with L_Date = 15/11/2018 and Y_Date = 14/11/2018, debugger returns:

[image]

Sorry for making a totally different code, but I hope it can helps.